# Location History & Nearby Devices (macOS & iOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, mac, ipad, geolocation

On Thursday last week, I was sitting at home in front of my MacBook Pro at my home in Brisbane, Australia. I also had my iPhone 12 Pro Max and iPad Air 4.

I have a proximity alert, triggered on my iPhone if my iPad is left behind.

All devices automatically connect to my home wifi (eero) and my iPad is often connected to my iPhone hotspot when I am out.

I require legally-binding proof that my iPad was in my possession at that time. What is the best way to obtain this proof?

Comment: First, you have to define for us what is considered “legally binding proof” then go about finding how you can supply that info.  I am not familiar with Aussie law, but in the US, the party making the claim would have to prove the defendant was, proof positive, in possession  of the item; they have the burden.

Comment: The alert you have set up notifies if the iPad is left behind. So any logs on the Mac (presuming there are any) would not have anything about the iPad unless it was "left behind." In strictly scientific terms "absence of evidence is not evidence of absence." Regardless of that what @Allan says is correct, you need to talk to a lawyer or other legal expert as to what the court will ask for in terms of location information on the iPad.

Comment: Allan, the accusation is that I gave my device to another person who submitted invalid data to a third-party app. I need to prove that I had my device in my possession so the invalid data could not have come from me.

Thank you Steve, the proximity alert can be ruled out.

I posted this question largely to find out if there is device specific location data that can be accessed on these devices, to corroborate the fact that I had them all together, in my personal posession.